# Pass value to different function in the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a form which contain an input. I would like to pass the input value into `data` function.

```
<form id="Form1" method="get" action="@Url.Action("data", "Home")">
<input class="form-control" name="name">
<button type="submit" value="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

This my controller. The function is a list. I want to use `name` value in SQL condition. When I run the program, it only display System.Collections.Generic.List`1

```
Public Function data(name As String) As List(Of order)
    Dim filter As New List(Of order)
    ...
    Where furniture.buyer.Contains(name)
    ...
    Return filter.ToList()
    End Function
```

Comment: You have not shown your `ActionResult` method that this form posts to (just a `Private` method that will never be executed when you submit because its `Private`)

Comment: updated. I am not sure how to pass the value

Comment: Change the method to `Public Function data(name As String) As ActionResult`

Comment: There is an error : "The value of list cannot be converted to actionresult". I do not want to display the list at the view. I want to pass the list to another function.

Comment: Read my comment - its `As ActionResult`! And your code is returning a `View`, not a `List<T>`

Comment: oh im sorry. it suppose to return a list

Comment: But its still a private function (and will not be called when you submit the form). Impossible to understand what your trying to do here.

Comment: I want to pass the 'name' value to data(). Thus I could use the value in SQL condition.Then I will return the result as list. So when Orders() function called data() it will retrieved a list of data. The error i get is : System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: Sorry, but its not making sense. Your calling a method which just returns `List<T>` It should either return a `View`. And I don't even know what you mean by _so when Orders() function_ - you have not shown any method named `Orders`.

Comment: yeah i want the method return as `List<T>`. So basically i only want to know how to pass the input value from view into `data()`